# How to retrieve access token, with parameters: Client_ID, Client_Secret, Auth_Url, Access_token_URL?

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

With the below code I receive:

```
{"data":{"error":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing","request":"\/oauth2\/token","method":"Post"}
```

```java
public class Authentication_Token {
    private String Client_ID = "9d99755c****d";
    private String Client_Secret= "dbdb21c0de1b***ab1d4cf6a4b92535ed2";
    private String Auth_URL= "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize";
    private String Access_Token_URL="https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token";

    @Test
    public void  oauth2() {
         // Still have the same error :                                                                                                                                                   
        Response resp = given()
            .contentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .parameters("Client ID", Client_ID,
                        "Client Secret", Client_Secret,
                        "username", "testbot@gmail.com",
                        "password", "testbota#1",
                        "grant_type", "authorization_Code",
                        "Access_Token_URL", Access_Token_URL)
            .auth()
                .preemptive().basic(Client_ID, Client_Secret)
            .post(Auth_URL);  
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using "Auth_URL" in the post? you should use the token URL, which is Access_Token_URL. am i missing something? there are 2 different URLs in oAuth, first GET and then POST (/token)

Comment: @umeshinator: Do you want to load the access token or the authorization code? The URL for the first is `/oauth2/token` and for the second is `/oauth2/authorize`.

Answer (score 0):

In Oauth 2.0 grant_type is a parameter and not a header.

See the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)

I suggest you use something like this :

```
given().parameters("username", "testbot@gmail.com", "password", "testbota#1", 
                           "grant_type", "Authorizaton_Code")
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I did changed my code a but as used grant_type inside parameters but still I have the same error, since there are two URL's Auth_URL & Access_Token_URL , is confusing how to pass those two URL's ?

Comment: auth_url is used to get the authorization_code and access_token url is used for the relying party to exchange that code for a token.